# Initialise Power set as anonymous interface

Tags: java, collections, powerset

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class PowerSet {

    public static final <E> Collection<Set<E>> of(Set<E> s) {
        List<E> src = new ArrayList<>(s);
        if (src.size() > 30) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Set too big " + s);
        }
        return new AbstractList<Set<E>>() {
            @Override
            public int size() {
                return 1 << src.size(); // 2 to the power srcSize
            }

            @Override
            public boolean contains(Object o) {
                return o instanceof Set && src.containsAll((Set) o);
            }

            @Override
            public Set<E> get(int index) {
                Set<E> result = new HashSet<>();
                for (int i = 0; index != 0; i++, index >>= 1) {
                    if ((index & 1) == 1) {
                        result.add(src.get(i));
                    }
                }
                return result;
            }
        };


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Collection<Set<String>> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add()...    }
```

I have this code I got from Java Effective as how implement
power set but I am confused how to initialise this set and 
fill it with values. There is interface with three overridden
methods, concretely contains, get and size. What does of in class
declaration mean?

Answer (score 0):

To initialize PowerSet instance you need to call it's constructor PowerSet(), though it'll be useless since there is no object related underlying logic in it.

"of" is a static method declared in PowerSet, accepting a set with size <= 30 and returning a List of Sets with logic of [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set). 
It is implemented by extension of AbstractList.

```
Set<Long> input = new HashSet<Long>();
input.add(1L);
input.add(2L);
List<Set<Long>> example = PowerSet.<Long>of(input);
```

So, `example.get(0)` will result with an empty HashSet, `example.get(1)` == {1}; `example.get(2)` == {2}, `example.get(3)` == {1, 2}

You can rewrite it in a more conventional format:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class PowerSet<E> extends AbstractList<Set<E>> { 

    private List<E> src;

    public PowerSet(Set<E> s){
       //copying set contains to a list to access by index
       src = new ArrayList<>(s);
    } 
    @Override
    public int size() {
        return 1 << src.size(); // 2 to the power srcSize
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return o instanceof Set && src.containsAll((Set) o);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<E> get(int index) {
        Set<E> result = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i = 0; index != 0; i++, index >>= 1) {
            if ((index & 1) == 1) {
                 result.add(src.get(i));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add()...  
        PowerSet<String> = new PowerSet(set);  

}
```

Comment: The first sample of code gives me error, that it doesn't find get method on example.get(0) etc. second code gives me is not abstract and doesn't  override method get(int)  that types are incompatible.

Comment: Change  public static final <E> Collection<Set<E>> of(Set<E> s)  to  public static final <E> List<Set<E>> of(Set<E> s) for the original example.

Comment: Or change public class PowerSet<E> extends AbstractList<Set<E>> in the second example (I have updated the code above). Let me know if you still have issues